# How to use the nuxt.js(SSR) on one segment of the WordPress(PHP) website

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, .htaccess, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I have a WordPress(or you can say PHP) application.
Every page is working fine and now I want to create a separate application named "marketing" under segment "/marketing".
For this, I am using Nuxt.js so I can use the [power of SSR](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/server-side-rendering/).

but I tried by updating the [base option](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-router#base) in nuxt.config.js as well but still the internal pages are not working.

```
export default {
  router: {
    base: '/'
  }
}
```

I think using `.htaccess` I can achieve this but still no luck.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^/marketing$ http://localhost:3000/ [P,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^/marketing/(.*)$ http://localhost:3000/$1 [P,L]

</IfModule>
```

Expected result

```
my-wp-site.com <--> Should render WordPress.
my-wp-site.com/contact-us <--> contact-us WordPress page.
my-wp-site.com/marketing <--> Should render Nuxt application.
my-wp-site.com/marketing/products <--> Should render Nuxt application's product page.
```

Right now, localhost:3000 i.e nuxt application is working fine. but when I open the `my-wp-site.com/marketing` URL then it renders the Home Page, but internal NuxtLink i.e. other pages are not working. routing is also not working.

Comment: base: '/app/' is obviously wrong. "not working" - what exactly is not working? It's unknown what's your environment and whether htaccess and mod_rewrite in particualr are efficient

Comment: I assume `http://localhost:3000/<url-path>` works as expected?

Comment: yes nuxt application is working.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
>     RewriteEngine On
>
>     RewriteRule ^/marketing$ http://localhost:3000/ [P,L]
>     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>     RewriteRule ^/marketing/(.*)$ http://localhost:3000/$1 [P,L]
>
> </IfModule>
> ```

Presumably you need to "forward" all requests that start `/marketing` (whole path segment), not just requests that don't map to files and directories?

In a `.htaccess` context the URL-path that the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against does not start with a slash, so the above would never match.

The `<IfModule>` wrapper should be removed.

You don't need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive if this already occurs later in the `.htaccess` file (as part of the WordPress code block).

The use of the `P` flag (that passes the request to mod_proxy) assumes you have already installed/enabled/configured mod_proxy and associated modules in the server config.

So, as far as `.htaccess` goes, you just need a one-liner - at the top of the `.htaccess` file, *before* any existing WordPress directives:

```
RewriteRule ^marketing(?:/(.*))?$ http://localhost:3000/$1 [P]
```

(The `L` flag is not required when the `P` flag is used.)